# Insert Multiple records from two table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a MySql database as follows:

```
1. Item_master(item_id, item_name, item_sp, item_op_stock)

2. customer_master (customer_id, customer_name, customer city )
```

I need to simultaneously insert an entry and create a new table to hold that entry.

Example entry

- Table name, "pricelist_details"
- Column called, 'sno' (primary_key)
- Column called, 'item_id' (from item table)
- Column called, 'customer_id' (from customer table)
- Column called, 'sp' (from item table)

How do I implement this with single INSERT statement?

Comment: How item table is related to customer table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
INSERT INTO pricelist_details
SELECT i.item_id,c.customer_id,i.sp 
FROM item i
CROSS JOIN customer  c
```

Comment: There is no item_id field in customer table. Item and Customer table are totally independent. pricelist table will contain entry for every combination of item_id and customer_id

Comment: @Saurabhtaparia Updated my answer